# Merging incremental data into full data

Tags: angular

My angular component loads the full data from server in the ngOnInit()-method:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.data$ = this.getInitialData();
}

getInitialData(): Observable<Player[]> {
  return of([
    {
       name: "Test Player 1",
       matches: 0
    },
    {
      name: "Test Player 2",
      matches: 0
    }
  ]);
}
```

This method sets the resulting Observable on the variable data$.
This variable will be used in the HTML-template in interaction with the async-pipe to actually subscribe to the full data load.

```html
<div *ngFor="let a of data$ | async">
  <span>{{a.name}}</span>
  <span>{{a.matches}}</span>
</div>
    
<button (click)="refresh()">refresh</button>
```

Furthermore a refresh-button exists in the HTML-template, which generates another Webservice request. Instead of loading the full data again, this Webservice will only respond with the incremental changes.

```js
refresh(): void {
  console.log("refresh button clicked");
  // TODO: when clicking the refresh button, the result of
  // getDiffData() should be merged into the result of the
  // initial getInitialData() and then be returned into the template via data$ | async
}

private requests = 0;

getDiffData() {
  return of([
    {
      name: "Test Player 2",
      matches: ++this.requests
    }
  ]);
}
```

I don't know how to merge the incremental data into the full data with a rxjs-way only.

I could to it in the way of subscribing inside the component.ts file and merge all data together (furthermore setting the merged data in a Subject and subscribe to it in the template), but there must be a RXJS-pattern, which I can use for it?

How my code actually looks: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hec61p-vgjyew?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-component.ts

Comment: can we assume that `name` is unique for your items? i mean we can find item in the existing array by name field?

Comment: Are you asking how to merge the new array into the existing one, given the possible overlap of names, all that using rxjs? Or simply how to "listen" to an Observable once with the `async` pipe and get the updates elegantly?

Comment: I am rather asking about correct "merge 2 arrays"  logic. can i assume that you have something like `mergeDataAndDiffArrays(data, diff)` implemented?

Comment: I don't think the actual merging is an rxjs challenge. But I may be wrong.

Comment: I see. but different people ask questions on SO. it may also be a challenge to someone

Comment: By rxjs challenge I meant that merging does not need to be resolved by using rxjs code per se. Everything else does.

Comment: yeah, the name is unique. And as Benny mentioned, the acutal merge-function is not the problem. The problem is how to unite both Observables (the one with full data, which will be executed once, and the one with the incremental data, which will be executed every time the refresh-button gets clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose to use `update$` as a subsject = source of refresh clicks and scan operator to unite the data

```
this.data$ =  concat(
      this.getInitialData(),
      this.update$.pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.getDiffData())
      )
    ).pipe( 
      scan((oldData, updateData) => mergeUpdates(oldData, updateData)), // could be [...oldData, ...updateData]
    );
```